# How to hide static files on React app deployed to Github pages?

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I've deployed my React app to GitHub Pages and I'm seeing all of my files and code in the `sources` tab. Here is a snippet of what I mean: [image: Static Files]

I've built my application using `react scripts build` and have tried pushing those files to my hosted Git repo as well as using the npm package `gh-pages` to push my build for me but all my code is still shown. Is there a way to hide these files on the deployed app or is this just how Githug Pages works since all my code is already in a public repo?

Answer (score 0):

You can never really hide the source since its runs in the browser, however when you run the build in 'production' mode, you minify and uglify the source to make it difficult to read it should just show 1 single chunk js file. In addition turn off source maps in your compiler settings (--no-source-maps).

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/

Comment: My build file does produce the minified code in the chunk.js files but for some reason the web app doesn't show these, it instead shows all the directories like the image in my question. Same result when I ran my build with --no-source-maps.